# Im an Angolan citizen, Do i need a transit visa to transit trough Amsterdan

Tags: schengen, transit-visas

I'll be travelling to Angola in June, via Amsterdam. however, Im just wondering if i will need a visa of any kind just to transit, my final destination is Luanda but im afraid ill have to have a schengen to successfully complete my trip! Can someone help me please :( T_T